# How I Pre-Populate Exiting Field Data in Gravity Forms

Tags: forms, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

Hay I have created a form by Gravity Forms for Registration for an event like this image: http://prntscr.com/7l3pf2

Now I want to create as much event forms as I need but I want to pre-populate Name and E-mail address by phone number from existing entry of any previous event form. Is it possible? How?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to "register" the user via the GF User Registration add-on. Then you can store their details in the user meta. On subsequent forms you can use the {user:meta_key} merge tag (i.e. {user:first_name}) in the Default Value setting to populate those details.